# Different numFound between SolrJ and Solr itself

Tags: solr

I and my team member are doing Solr indexing recently but bounced into some problems that we searched and searched yet no documents about that.

Its that we use the same query in SolrJ and on Solr Admin UI query
like "callleeID : 12 AND fraudType : (7 8 9 10)" 
on exactly same table,

but I get different numFound from them, for SolrJ, totalCount = 4251, as for when I use Solr admin query, I get numFound = 4263.

Please tell me what happened and what I can do to fix it?

Below I link the two screen shots to show those differences.

[screen shot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N46uj.png)

[screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YBtL.png)

Comment: could you show SolrJ java code that sends this query?

Comment: It is a large project involved with lots of other methods, I do not know how to  show it, but I can guarantee that the query syntax has no problem.

Comment: you mean, you're 100% sure, that both queries are similar?

Comment: Compare the logged query from both instances to see that they're _actually_ identical, instead of assuming that they represent the same thing in different interfaces. Are we talking about a distributed cluster or a single node?

Comment: I am sure, the syntax is perfect and this is the only different result we get between solrJ and solr

Comment: It is an single node

Comment: Are the queries logged _identically_ in the actual Solr log (you can see, and tweak, the logging level under Logging in the admin pane)? Please show the log entries and not the debug screenshots. Are the max scores identical? What does `debugQuery` show for both queries?

Answer (score 0):

In Solr admin UI try using `+` instead of `AND`:

```
+callleeID:12
+fraudType:(7 8 9 10)
```

Comment: will these two make big difference?

Comment: I said "try"... I mean this is how you normally do "and" command in Solr UI - adding `+` to every item you want to be included into filtering